# Select rows from SQL table within file size range

Tags: sql, sqlite, between

I have a column in my table that represents file sizes in human-friendly format. For example, 25MB, 300B, 76.5KB etc.. How would I write a query that would select rows that were within a size range? For example between 150kb and 6mb or betwe 35mb and 1.2GB?

I've learned how to order by file size which is a similar issue, but I haven't been able to use that for these purposes.

I can get a range of files that are sort of in my range, but files like 9mb will be ordered higher than 150mb files.

Comment: Store the file size in a constant unit for all rows, I'd suggest bytes, then filter by that. Leave a separate column for the human-readable values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know I could do that, and that query would be easy. But that is not what I am trying to solve. But I want it done this way for my current project.

Comment: In that case you would need to hack together some ugly logic to figure out the size in bytes based on the human-readable string. This will not be fast or extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by storing with [`Row Values`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) inside a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) the values in Bytes of each one of B, KB, MB, GB and TB and use them when you want to perform search:

```
with cte(suffix, bytes) as (
  select * from (
    values 
      ('B', 1), ('KB', 1024), ('MB', 1024 * 1024), 
      ('GB', 1024 * 1024 * 1024), ('TB', 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
  )
)
select f.* from filtered f 
where 
  f.size * (select max(bytes) from cte where f.size like '%' || suffix) 
  between 
  '150MB' * (select max(bytes) from cte where '150MB' like '%' || suffix) 
  and 
  '6GB' * (select max(bytes) from cte where '6GB' like '%' || suffix)
```

Replace `'150MB'` and `'6GB'` with your search values.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gA2pgwB4JZfCN8HcTWkjd5/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the value to an actual number.  One method would be to explicitly translate each suffix:

```
select (case when size like '%KB' then 1000
             when size like '%MB' then 1000000
             when size like '%GB' then 1000000000
             else 1
        end) * (size + 0.0)
from table_name 
where size between 750 and 1000
```

Two notes.  Suffixes such as "MB" are ambiguous.  It can mean either 1,000,000 or 2^20 (1,048,576).  That means that the factors might be different.

The `size + 0.0` uses SQLite's capability to do implicit conversion, based on leading numeric digits.